# Holder.js -- Get back DOM element?

Tags: javascript, holder.js

[holder.js](http://imsky.github.com/holder/)

I want to dynamically add a placeholder image to my page.

Inserting it like so doesn't work:

```
$('<li>',{class:'file-item'})
    .append($('<img>',{'data-src':'holder.js/150x150'}))
    .append($('<span>',{class:'file-name'}).text(file.name))
    .appendTo('#file-list');
```

Because the holder script has already ran and isn't searching for new elements.

We can, however, run it again manually:

```
Holder.run()
```

But then it will scan all the elements that are already added.

So...is there way I can get holder.js to create and give me back a DOM element so I can add it manually without re-running the whole thing?

Comment: Holder is a jQuery plugin? Something else?

Comment: Seems like there is an `add_image` method that could possibly handle this

Comment: ...beware of `{class:'file-name'}`. It'll break in some older browsers. Use `className` or `"class"`.

Comment: @thesystem: holder.js is a standalone library for generating placeholder images. It's used in Twitter Bootstrap. Added link to question.

Comment: @thesystem: Excellent point about the `class` property. I did run into that before (in IE I think) and it confused the heck out of me. Gave a very misleading error.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Reading through the `add_image` src...looks weird. It creates an image element with the source you provde, and then appends it to an element for you.... I don't want it to do the appending, and also it doesn't look like it's running the image generation code on it either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass a `Node` as the `images` property to `Holder.run` and you'll be able to run Holder on any individual image. Holder itself doesn't create a DOM element, it just changes the `src` value.

Code:

```
var image = $("<img>").attr({
    "data-src": "holder.js/300x200"
})

Holder.run({
    images: image[0]
});

image.appendTo("body");
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/p3DMa/

Comment: You can even do it before it's appended to the DOM that way! Nice!

Comment: same as above just for dynamic dives `Holder.run({
        images: $("#" + "img" + obj.rId).find('img')[0]
    });`